# converting comma separated data of excel file into new line using python, pandas

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas, csv, data-analysis

I have an excel file with data as

```
StudentId    Details
1234         John, Texas, United States
9887         Roma, Moscow, Russia
```

I want to convert it into the following format, such that:

```
StudentId    Details
1234         John
             Texas
             United States 

9887         Roma
             Moscow
             Russia
```

I am using Pandas for this purpose but not getting the results

```
for i in range(len(df['Details'])):
    df['Details'][i]=df['Details'][i].replace(',','\n')
```

I am using somewhat this kind of logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read it in with `read_fwf()` then split up that column later:

```
df['Details'].str.split(',')
```

Comment: import pandas as pd
    df = pd.read_fwf("data.xlsx")
    df['Details'].str.split(',')

I am new to this field, I tried to use it as suggested by you but it is giving some unreadable output

Comment: Oh I missed you are reading an excel file. See `pd.read_excel()`

Comment: No, it is giving result in the same line as:

[' John', 'Texas', 'United States']